# TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kind'

Tags: python, plotly, typeerror

I am working through a [Kaggle tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/code/anand0427/network-graph-with-at-t-data-using-plotly/notebook) on a network graphic with plotly. After some updating to get the code compatible with chart_studio, I am now getting the error:

```
TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kind'
```

The code I have entered to try and get the graph is:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

#AT&T network data
network_df=pd.read_csv('network_data.csv')

#source_ip and destination_ip are of our interest here. so we isolate them. We then get the unique ip addresses for getting
#the total number of nodes. We do this by taking unique values in both columns and joining them together.

A = list(network_df["source_ip"].unique())
B = list(network_df["destination_ip"].unique())
node_list = set(A+B)

#Creating the Graph

G = nx.Graph()

#Graph api to create an empty graph. And the below cells we will create nodes and edges and add them to our graph
for i in node_list:
    G.add_node(i)

G.nodes()

pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.5, iterations=50)

for n, p in pos.items():
    G.nodes[n]['pos'] = p

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    line=dict(width=0.5,color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')

for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.node[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.node[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_trace['x'] += tuple([x0, x1, None])
    edge_trace['y'] += tuple([y0, y1, None])

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    text=[],
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(
        showscale=True,
        colorscale='RdBu',
        reversescale=True,
        color=[],
        size=15,
        colorbar=dict(
            thickness=10,
            title='Node Connections',
            xanchor='left',
            titleside='right'
        ),
        line=dict(width=0)))

for node in G.nodes():
    x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
    node_trace['x'] += tuple([x])
    node_trace['y'] += tuple([y])

for node, adjacencies in enumerate(G.adjacency()):
    node_trace['marker']['color']+=tuple([len(adjacencies[1])])
    node_info = adjacencies[0] +' # of connections: '+str(len(adjacencies[1]))
    node_trace['text']+=tuple([node_info])

#Start plotting
fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
             layout=go.Layout(
                title='<br>AT&T network connections',
                titlefont=dict(size=16),
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=20,l=5,r=5,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                    text="No. of connections",
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref="paper", yref="paper") ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False)))

#the above code gave me an error because it wasn't set up for chart_studio

iplot(fig)
plotly.plot(fig)

from chart_studio.plotly import plot
from chart_studio import plotly
import plotly
import chart_studio

chart_studio.tools.set_credentials_file(username='anand0427', api_key='5Xd8TlYYqnpPY5pkdGll')

iplot(fig,"anand0427",filename="Network Graph.html")

iplot(fig)
plotly.plot(fig)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have looked around trying to figure out what kind means and how to adapt it for this graph.

Full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-e49e5cb9a1e3> in <module>()
      2 
      3 iplot(fig)
----> 4 plotly.plot(fig)

TypeError: plot() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kind'
```

Comment: Please share the whole stack trace, there's usually important information there to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Hi. I edited my post to include that. Sorry.

Comment: Hum, OK, still not enough, sorry. Please try to make your code reproducible. I.e., we should be able to cut and paste it to run it ourselves, so it should have required imports and define all that's needed for it to run. And maybe add a link to that tutorial and the data files. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you improve the question. Someone doing the same tutorial as you might be able to answer your question as is, but the rest of the SO community probably won't, you have to give us more info.

Comment: Ok. So I added my import statements and previous code in. With all this, what I get when I run the final output is the error. I also linked to the tutorial. Thanks for the tips, it is really helping me get my bearings here.

Comment: Hmm, in that tutorial, it looks like the `iplot(fig)` command works, but the `plotly.plot(fig)` command is never actually shown to work, that's a bit odd to me to be honest. Do you get the graph they show with your call to `iplot`?

Comment: Also, in both your code and the tutorial, I would advise against combining `from chart_studio import plotly` with `import plotly`: that's defining the same name twice, which probably means only the second instance remains defined. Do you really want to call `chart_studio.plotly.plot()` or `plotly.plot()` from the `plotly` package itself? I would change your import statements to make that unambiguous.

Comment: Hmmm. so I commented out the second ```import plotly``` and the kind error that I asked about went away. However, there is no chart that shows up. I tried adding ```fig. show()``` but no dice. However, the error is gone, so you did technically answer my question. I just need to figure out why the window is blank.

Comment: Well, you're one step further, anyway... Good luck with the next step!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the ambiguous import statements that both your code and the tutorial use.

You have

```
from chart_studio import plotly
import plotly
```

which means that you define `plotly` twice, and only the second definition remains. The tutorial has the same problem, with `from plotly import plotly` followed by `import plotly`.

So when you call `plotly.plot()`, you're not calling `chart_studio.plotly.plot()`, which I believe is your intention, but instead you're calling the `plot()` function defined in `plotly/__init__.py`, whose [in-code documentation](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/packages/python/plotly/plotly/__init__.py) says it's not intended to be called directly.

Unless you know you need it, remove the line `import plotly`, or change one of those two import lines to say `as <some other name>`, which will let you refer to `chart_studio.plotly` and the base `plotly` by different, unambiguous names.

Answer (score 1):

TypeError: plot() is missing one required positional argument: 'kind'
If this error happens, check  weather plotly.offline is imported (if you are imported plotly only)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you elaborate?